# Copy std::vector into std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

How do I copy or move the first `n` elements of a `std::vector<T>` into a C++11 `std::array<T, n>`?

Comment: [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).

Comment: Do you want to copy, or move? These are different things.

Comment: Depending on what `::std::vector` contains, `::std::memcpy` and `::std::memmove` could also be used.

Comment: or in C++ the `std::uninitialized_copy` :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n)

```
std::array<T, N> arr;
std::copy_n(vec.begin(), N, arr.begin());
```

Edit: I didn't notice that you'd asked about moving the elements as well. To move, wrap the source iterator in [`std::move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator).

```
std::copy_n(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()), N, arr.begin());
```

Comment: Here N is const? array<T,N> N should be const.

Comment: @notbad Yes, `N` is const (guess I should've used `n` as posted in the question)

Comment: There's also `std::move`. Sadly, not `std::move_n`.

Comment: what happens if the size N is wrong? i.e. vector has 5 elements, array wants to copy 10? The cpp doc page is a bit unclear on this.

Comment: @peterkarasev The number of elements you pass to `copy_n` needs to be the minimum of the sizes of the vector and the array. Otherwise you'll either read beyond the bounds of the source or write beyond the bounds of the destination, both of which are undefined behavior.

Comment: @Praetorian undefined... so, some compiler might throw exception, elsewhere it will overwrite some memory? I would hope it throws exception, otherwise what's the gain over the raw array that silently trashes memory when going out of bounds?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
int n = 2;
std::vector<int> x {1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 2> y;
std::copy(x.begin(), x.begin() + n, y.begin());
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74e11b9574985cee)'s the live example.

If you want to move, instead, you can use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move):

```
int n = 2;
std::vector<int> x {1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 2> y;
std::move(x.begin(), x.begin() + n, y.begin());
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2feae9b6f0aa7af)'s the other live example.

Comment: What about the `n`? Shouldn't it be `std::copy(x.begin(), x.begin() + n, y.begin());`?

Comment: Instead of using a variable such as `n`, wouldn't it be better to use `x.size()`?

Comment: You could use `x.size()` but it won't compile - N here is a compile-time constant and even a template parameter.
The `std::array` is simply like an array - it requires a size known at compile time.
Period.